# Jquery change/click not working with visualforce tags

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jquery from visualforce page. Have added the min.js library file too..Below is the code piece sample. I'm able to get 1st alert output i.e. - 'ready to go' inside document.ready function  but after that the click/change function is not working .

```
<script>
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

j$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('ready to go');

    $('[id$=idAccFName]').click(function(){
    alert('Clicked in First Name');

    $('[id$=idAccFName]').change(function(){
    alert('Changed First Name');

    xyz = $('[id$=idAccFName]').text();
    alert('xyz='+xyz);
    });
});  
</script>
```

VF Page :

```
<apex:inputField id="idAccFName" value="{!cr.FirstName_AGN__c}"  required="true" rendered="{!viewReadWrite}"  />
<apex:inputField id="idAccLName" value="{!cr.Last_Name_AGN__c}" required="true" rendered="{!viewReadWrite}"/> 

<apex:inputField id="idAccFName" value="{!cr.First_Name__c}"  required="true"/>
<apex:inputField id="idAccLName" value="{!cr.Last_Name__c}" required="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got the syntax corrected...its working  thanks..

```
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

j$(document).ready(function(){
    j$("[id$='idAccLName']").change(function(){
    alert('Last Name = ' + j$("[id$='idAccLName']").val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You should run all your `Javascript` code through **[JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/)**.

You're not closing your first `click` function. It's just:

```
$(selector).click(function () {
```

When it should be:

```
$(selector).click(function () {
}); // <-- missing these
```

Though really, you don't need two and should just remove the first one.

Take a look at [Self-Executing Anonymous Functions](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/). This pattern will help you clean up your code. You also no longer have to worry about `noConflict`.

```
(function (w, $) {
    "use strict";
    $(function () {
        $('[id$=idAccFName]').click(function () {
            w.alert('click handler');
        });
    });
}(window, jQuery));
```

Comment: That's a cool JS feature, but based on your link, the self executing syntax should be `(function(arg1){...})(arg1param);`, you have `(function(arg1){...}(arg1param));`.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian See also: [JSLint Error Explanations - Move the invocation into the parens that contain the function](https://jslinterrors.com/move-the-invocation-into-the-parens-that-contain-the-function) and [this version](http://blog.mgechev.com/2012/08/29/self-invoking-functions-in-javascript-or-immediately-invoked-function-expression/). I find that Dalgleish has the most accessible explanation of how IIFE works, so that's what I link.

Comment: [Also of interest](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/225)

Comment: Oh cool, so both ways work.